# How to update state in react native expo on button click

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, countdowntimer

I used react-native-countdown-timer component. I have used useEffect previously to start timer which is running perfectly but when I change to on press function react state is not updating

This is the Code of Component

```
const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);

const OnCountDown = () => {
    var date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    var expirydate = moment().add(4, "hours").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"); //You can set your own date-time
    console.log(date);
    console.log(expirydate);
    var diffr = moment.duration(moment(expirydate).diff(moment(date)));
    var hours = parseInt(diffr.asHours());
    var minutes = parseInt(diffr.minutes());
    var seconds = parseInt(diffr.seconds());
    var d = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
    setTotalDuration(d);
  };



<IconButton
              icon={"qrcode-scan"}
              size={40}
              onPress={() => {
                setOnline(true);
                OnCountDown();
              }}
            />

<CountDown
          until={totalDuration}
          timeToShow={["H", "M", "S"]}
          onFinish={() => alert("finished")}
          // onPress={() => alert("hello")}
          size={20}
        />
```

Comment: Can you post a full example?

Comment: this is the full example

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is to start counter on a button press and you couldn't achieve that because there isn't any option for start the counter for `react-native-countdown-timer component` since its working is to provide duration on initial phase and it will auto start.
So to achieve what you want there were some alternative libraries

1. [react-native-flip-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flip-countdown-timer) : which have `play` [props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flip-countdown-timer#countdowntimer-props) and
2. [react-native-stopwatch-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stopwatch-timer) : which have `start` [props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stopwatch-timer#stopwatch-and-timer-options)

which are boolean, you can set this to true on button press.

Comment: there is a method of start and stop which takes boolean

Comment: @IbrahimShabbir can you share the link to your used library